# HTTP header is being sent, but isn't present in Request.Headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My api side code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Login")]
public HttpResponseMessage ValidateLogin(UserModel user)
{
    IEnumerable<string> customJsonInputString;

    if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Type", out customJsonInputString))
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    var customJsonInputArray = customJsonInputString.ToArray();

    var ProductsRequest =
      Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(customJsonInputArray[0]);

    var result = _service.Fetch(
            new UserModel
            {
                Username = user.Username,
                Password = user.Password.GenerateHash()
            }
        );
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
}
```

I'm trying to call it from the separate project which is in the same solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UserLoginModel user)
{
    UserModel data = new UserModel
    {
        Username = user.Username,
        Password = user.Password
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var endpoint = "http://localhost:55042/api/Login";

        var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, byteContent);

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem I think is in `Request.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Type", out customJsonInputString)`-s first parameter name, I have searched the web, but haven't come up with the proper description/explanation what that parameter name should be(well, I get that it's a header name, but I tried to find it also with "ContentType" and result is the same: "400 bad request"), so my questions are:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Is it wrong that I assumed the name of the header would be "ContentType" or "Content-Type" ?

Comment: Do not dispose `HttpClient` on every request! https://josefottosson.se/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `HttpWebRequest` instead of `HttpClient`, had some more problems but finally everything is figured out. [How i chose to proceed and next problem which is already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385632/web-api-not-receiving-the-json-of-serialized-object#55386584)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your code like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);                
            var endpoint = "http://localhost:55042/api/Login";    
            var response = await client.PostAsync(endpoint, new StringContent(myContent, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header resides in `Request.Content.Headers`. You can use your current code to get headers values or check if `Request.Content.Headers.ContentType` property equals `null`

```
//note added Content
if (!Request.Content.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Type", out customJsonInputString))
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

or

```
if (Request.Content.Headers.ContentType == null)
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

`ContentType` property equals `null` even when `Content-Type` header is set but is invalid.