# Web API not receiving the json of serialized object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

client side code:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UserLoginModel user)
    {
        UserModel data = new UserModel
        {
            Username = user.Username,
            Password = user.Password.GenerateHash()
        };

        var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        var url = "http://localhost:55042/api/Login";

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(serializedData);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        bool deserializedResult = false;
        using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (httpWebRequest.HaveResponse && response != null) {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
                    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(result);
                }
            }
        }

        return deserializedResult ? View() : throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Web API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Login")]
    public IHttpActionResult ValidateLogin([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        var result = _service.FetchUser(user);

        return Json(result);
    }
```

UserModel

```
[Serializable]
public class UserModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string NumberI { get; set; }

    public string NumberII { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

No data arrives in ValidateLogin, even when I pass parameters with the postman.

I have searched **a lot**, found no solution at all, tried all the code snippets, understood them then came back and so on,  I'm stuck, what is wrong?

Comment: can you provide definition of the UserModel class. From Postman when you send request whats the http status code you recieving back ?

Comment: @Vishnu 200 OK, [UserModel](https://imgur.com/a/uFg4Y4h)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Just remove `[Serializable]` attribute from `UserModel` and everything will work fine.

**Solution 2**

When serializing data on client use json serialization behavior as `Web API` does

```
var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        IgnoreSerializableAttribute = false
    }
});
```

Now `Web API` will correctly deserialize passed model.

This happens because starting from some version `Json.NET` considers if object is marked as `Serializable`. By default without that attribute all public members (properties and fields) are serialized. Serialization of the following class

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

gives the following result

```
{
  "Username": "name",
  "Password": "pass"
}
```

But when class is marked by `[Serializable]` attribute and `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` setting is `false` all private and public fields are serialized and result is the following

```
{
  "<Username>k__BackingField": "name",
  "<Password>k__BackingField": "pass"
}
```

By default serializer ignores `[Serializable]` attribute but in `Web API` the `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` is set to `false`. So now it's easy to see why server couldn't properly deserialize given model in your case.